# When is an UDP connection treated as UDP stream

Tags: networking, udp, firewall, nat

In NAT there are two different timeouts for a UDP session.

- UDP timeout
- UDP stream timeout

The `UDP timeout` is set to `30 seconds` in most NAT configurations. However, the `UDP stream timeout` is set to `180 seconds`. I understand that the configurations may be changed by the network administrator. However, a UDP session is identified by a pair of source and destination endpoints. And the NAT is supposed to classify the connection as a stream.

My question is how and when the `NAT` classifies a connection as a stream and when it does not? Although it seems that a pair of consecutive bidirectional `send()`, and `receive()` classifies the UDP connection as a stream, I don't find a documented evidence.

Also, I suppose different NAT policies apply different algorithms. But is there any RFC or any published paper that documents those algorithms?

In the following [link](https://community.ubnt.com/t5/EdgeRouter/UDP-connection-timeout/m-p/1341527/highlight/true#M77742) stream is defined as a session that has communication in both directions. But how many send and receives are required ? Does that vary in different NATs ?

> In this context, "stream" means the connection tracking mechanism has
>   seen packets in "both directions" so the default timeout is longer. If
>   only one direction has been seen, the "other" timeout applies.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when a LAN client sends a UDP datagram to a WAN, a NAT associates a UDP stream (aka *port state*) with the port used for sending the datagram to the WAN. When the NAT receives a UDP datagram from WAN on a specific port it looks to see whether there is a UDP stream associated with that port and if so, it forwards the datagram to the associates LAN client. Otherwise the datagram is dropped.

When two different LAN clients want to send UDP datagrams to each other over WAN, a common practice to traverse their NATs is [*UDP hole punching*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching): both clients start sending datagrams to each other from/to the same port, so that their NATs assocate the UDP streams and start forwarding the datagrams.

Comment: But my question is when does a NAT decide to treat a UDP connection as stream?

Comment: @AkashChowdhury When it receives a UDP datagram from LAN to WAN.

Comment: In several experiments I have done it doesn't. However after few bidirectional LAN <-> WAN communications it decides that connection to be a stream. Only a single LAN to WAN datagram does not mark it as a stream and a 30 seconds idle time is used by the router. Please check the updated question.

Comment: @AkashChowdhury You completely rewrote your question. I suggest you check documentation for your NAT.

Comment: Yes previously it was unclear, what I am asking. I think now it is more clear.